# Skype not showing in Unity panel

Tags: apt, software-installation, skype

I have installed the `Ubuntu 12.04 (multiarch)` version of Skype from the [official Skype website](http://www.skype.com/en/download-skype/skype-for-computer/), and yet when I launch it, I cannot see the little Skype icon in the Unity Panel as I have seen it on other machines. I have even gone into my Skype setting and asked it to minimize to the system tray on startup, and still I get nothing.

Why is this? And how can I fix it? On the other machine where I have seen this working Skype was installed through the command:

```
sudo apt-get install skype
```

And not through downloading and installing the `.deb` file from the Skype website like I did, could this be causing the difference? And if so, should I uninstall Skype, and try installing it from the partner repository? Or can this not be what is making the difference?

---

**OS Information:**

```
Description:    Ubuntu 15.04
Release:    15.04
```

**Package Information:**

[image: Skype about section]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Installing Skype from the website does not install these additional dependencies:

- `libdbusmenu-qt2:i386`
- `sni-qt:i386`

One of which (`sni-qt:i386`) is needed for this functionality, so either just install this additional dependency with:

```
sudo apt-get install sni-qt:i386
```

Or replace your current Skype installation with the one from the repository which will install the extra stuff and remove the Skype you installed from the website (which is known as `skype:i386`):

```
sudo apt-get install skype
```

Comment: It is not installed, you could solve?

Comment: @ParanoidPanda: Well, you'd better drop skype-bin from that list. skype-bin is only involved when installing from the Canonical partner repository.