# How to get skype window/indicator back

Tags: 12.04, indicator, skype

On Ubuntu 12.04

Older version of skype, I used to get indicator on top right and I could activate skype by clicking appropriate items.

With newer skype version (4.3.0.37), I don't get indicator/icon. If I close skype window so that it won't clutter my task bar, how can I get skype window back? I have verified skype process is still running

Comment: So you don't want to have the indicator icon? Or you do? Or you want to open Skype without having that indicator icon?

Comment: I would prefer to have indicator icon if that's possible

Comment: Are you running Unity? And how did you install Skype? From the website?

Comment: Yes, running unity and skype is installed from the deb file downloaded from skype site.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Skype not showing in Unity panel](http://askubuntu.com/questions/649585/skype-not-showing-in-unity-panel)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing Skype from the website does not install these additional dependencies:

- `libdbusmenu-qt2:i386`
- `sni-qt:i386`

One of which (`sni-qt:i386`) is needed for this functionality, so either just install this additional dependency with:

```
sudo apt-get install sni-qt:i386
```

Or replace your current Skype installation with the one from the repository which will install the extra stuff and remove the Skype you installed from the website (which is known as `skype:i386`):

```
sudo apt-get install skype
```

This should work for Unity, however if you are using Gnome then you should [install](https://askubuntu.com/a/757326/364819) this extension: [Appindicator Support](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/615/appindicator-support/).

Also please don't say that I am just ripping off [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/649595/364819), because if you look in the edit history for it, you will see that I basically wrote it all anyway.

Comment: I tried installing both packages -libdbusmenu and sni-qt . System says its already latest version

Comment: @user871199: Which version did you download from the site? The multiarch version? Or the other one? You should try installing skype with `sudo apt-get install skype`, that will uninstall the old one you have, and add everything needed, that should work, if not, it might be that it doesn't work on your system and you need to upgrade.